# WebDriverException thrown in Python for Selenium driver for Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I ran the following commands in Python to instantiate a Selenium webdriver for Chrome, but got an exception. Previously (a few days ago) there was no error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 65, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 123, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"aux
Data":{"frameId":"9716.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc
1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

There are also errors of the form:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 141, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 199, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 426, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1132, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 453, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 480, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by upgrading the Chromedriver.exe to 2.25: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/

(Most likely the version of Chrome had been updated automatically, which required the Chromedriver to be updated as well.)